# Are you supposed to check-in R.java file in to VCS?

Tags: android, git, version-control, r.java-file

Very basic question. I plan to do our builds via Hudson and have android apk files available for download there. Is R.java in the /gen directory something that you check-in with you VCS? Or is it something that needs to be ignored and android sdk will generate every time if it doesn't exist?

Comment: I love stackover flow. Got an answer in less time than I expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The entire `gen` folder is automatically generated and shouldn't be checked into VCS.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in gen should go into your repository.
Add gen to your .gitignore to avoid mistakes/cluttered git status.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to include any of the gen/ files. You must exclude the gen directory itself, otherwise you could ran into problems when updating/committing to git or any other VCS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ignore this file. Ant build task create this file.